# how to use dispatch_apply to replace nested for loop of GCD to get maximum concurrent performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, for-loop, processing-efficiency

I have a nested for loop. I want to optimise it using GCD concurrency. Tried:

1. Replace both for loop with gcd_apply.
2. Replaced only inner for loop with gcd_apply.

I want to get final out put same without change in order.

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getsportNotificationObjectsByGroup{
NSMutableArray* notificationObjects = [NSMutableArray array];

NSString* defaultNoteValue;
defaultNoteValue = [WADeviceAndAppSettingPopUpManager getDefaultNoteValueBasedOnSystemAlertButtonAction];

for(WACategoryInfo * categoryInfo in self.allSportSCategories){
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSMutableArray *subArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];;
        for (NSDictionary *dictNotificationTags in categoryInfo.notificationTags) {
            NSString *tagName, *tagCode;
            BOOL isTagDefaultEnabled = NO;
            tagName = [dictNotificationTags objectForKeyWithNullCheck:ktagName];
            tagCode = [dictNotificationTags objectForKeyWithNullCheck:ktagCode];
            isTagDefaultEnabled = [[dictNotificationTags objectForKeyWithNullCheck:kisTagDefaultEnabled] boolValue];

            //********value computation*******//



            NSString* val = @"";
            if ([WAConfigLoader sharedInstance].isCollegeStyleApp) {
                val = [WADeviceAndAppSettingPopUpManager getValueForSwitch:dictNotificationTags];

            }
            //*****value computation*********//
            NSDictionary *sportDetail =  @{
                                           kname:tagName,
                                           ktype:kswitch,
                                           kid:tagCode,
                                           kvalue : val,
                                           ksportStringId:categoryInfo.sportStringID,
                                           kTitleKey : tagName
                                           };

            [subArray addObject:sportDetail];

        }

        NSMutableDictionary *aNewDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [aNewDict setObject:subArray forKey:kdata];
        [aNewDict setObject:categoryInfo.sportTitle forKey:ksection];
        [notificationObjects addObject:aNewDict];
    }
}
return notificationObjects;
```

}

It's not mandatory to use GCD only, my concern is to maximise loop performance.

Comment: "I want to get final out put same without change in order." Well, if you're doing stuff concurrently, you just don't have control over the order it completes, plain and simple. So, refactor your code so that it doesn't matter. E.g. store results in dictionary and then go back to the original array to figure out the order with which you should retrieve them from the dictionary.

Comment: You say that you've tried dispatch apply. So, don't ask us to write it again, but instead show us what you tried. Setting aside the order of the results, how was it otherwise? What sort of performance gain did you get? If the code isn't sufficiently computationally intensive, you might not see significant improvements (esp after you add the necessary overhead to synchronize there results).

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the inner loop with `dispatch_apply`, you have to take concern of these drawbacks:

- You have to sync the call to `[subArray addObject]`
- The order in `subArray` is indetermined

Therefore, I would recomment to only put the outer loop in a `dispatch_apply` work item, because it's results are added to a dictionary which does not provide any order. Nevertheless, you'd have to sync `[notificationObjects addObject]` anyway.

Just remember to dispatch_apply into a *concurrent* queue.